# Signature validation based on the XMLSec standard

Tags: certificate, xml

I've run into issues verifying the **signature** of an **XML** file based on the **XMLSec** standard.

I'm running:

> xmlsec1 1.2.19 (openssl)

Here's the **certificate** used for validation:

> wget -O cert.pem
>   http://pastie.org/pastes/8532183/text?key=r4juxvisjzv9s7rqbkv1dw

And the actual **.xml**:

> wget -O file.xml
>   http://www.nordea.fi/sitemod/upload/root/content/nordea_fi_fi/yritysasiakkaat/yhteys_pankkiin/muut/SOAPrequest_GetUserInfo.xml

The command line I'm using to perform the signature validation:

> xmlsec1 --verify --pubkey-cert-pem cert.pem --id-attr:Id Body file.xml

And the error I'm getting:

> func=xmlSecOpenSSLEvpDigestVerify:file=digests.c:line=250:obj=sha1:subj=unknown:error=12:invalid
>   data:data and digest do not match
>   FAIL
>   SignedInfo References (ok/all):
>   0/1 Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
>   Error: failed to verify file
>   "file.xml"

Ideas as to what I might be doing wrong (maybe the **--id-attr** param should be different)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digest has actually been calculated w/ an error by a 3rd party.